# Maven Dependency issue

Tags: maven-3

I have an EAR project which has an EJB module included, now my question is why I have to include the third party dependency both in EAR pom and as well as in EJB pom?

Can't I put the dependency in only EJB POM???

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add third party dependency on EAR POM ! you must add these depencencies only on EJB POM and add EJB as a depencency on EAR POM.and finally these dependencies goes to lib folder of EAR module.